# What control engineering techniques are used for the landing maneuvers of Falcon 9-R?

Tags: spacex, landing, attitude, falcon-9, aerodynamics

Which are the main control theories behind the landing maneuvers of the Falcon 9? For the hovering part, as it approaches the landing surface, I guess the [inverted pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) control approaches would do it. But what about the control from stage separation till it the reentry burn? Any textbook references appreciated!

Comment: Oddly, no hovering.  The engine has a T/W ratio greater than 1.  Cannot hover, even if they wanted too.  Cannot throttle down low enough to hover.

Comment: Duplicate? [How will SpaceX achieve landing of the Falcon 9 first stage?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6679/how-will-spacex-achieve-landing-of-the-falcon-9-first-stage)

Comment: Not sure, seems to be asking about "control theories", which probably includes the algorithms computing location and guidance. The question you pose as a duplicate is about the hardware.

Comment: Something like [this](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/31085/46605171.pdf)? -- old stuff.

Comment: Well you're right geoffc. I've might have used the term "hovering" wrong. Although at the very last moment the velocity would be zero... and in the previous missions it hovered a little bit on the surface of the ocean. Fantastic thesis mins. Thanks, that will get me definitely started! Old stuff indeed... but the implementation is quite new and exciting!

Comment: @mins The URL no longer works, any possibility of finding a new link? I'm interested in what you linked.

Comment: @space_voyager: [A Predictor-Corrector Guidance Algorithm Design for a Low L/D Autonomous Re-entry Vehicle by Carla Haroz, 1996](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/31085/46605171-MIT.pdf?sequence=2)

Comment: @KonstantinosV To add to this (old) discussion, I worked with a guy from JPL whose past colleague (Lars Blackmore) is now the guy responsible for Falcon 9 landing. They use real-time convex optimization by harnessing *lossless convexification* of a non-convex optimal control problem (the non-convexity arises, for example, from a non-zero lower bound on Merlin engine thrust). [Here's a paper on the topic](http://behcet.ae.utexas.edu/sites/default/files/gfold_aas_13_0.pdf)

Comment: @space_voyager - Lars Blackmore's page (http://web.mit.edu/larsb/www/) and his publication list give a good approximation of the algos he designed. That's as good as it gets, barring a tweet by Elon. You could convert your comment to an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the key control algorithms involved is called G-FOLD, or Guidance for Fuel-Optimal Large Diverts. This is something that JPL has been working on for Mars landings, and some people involved have actually went to work for SpaceX a few years ago.
Here is a high level description:

http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/marsconcepts2012/pdf/4193.pdf

And you can find more here :
https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=xZvK9z0AAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate