# Falcon 9 landing stages

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reentry, landing, reuse

I know the first stage of Falcon 9 separates at about 2:30 min and it lands at about 8:30 min

But what are the distinct stages of the descent? Like deorbit burns, grid fin deployment, leg deployment etc.
And their timings

Comment: There are two different kinds of Falcon's 1st stage return - landing on land and landing on the floating platform. Depending on that there are two different sequences of mission stages and timings. I suppose all of them can be seen on SpaceX onboard videos. https://www.youtube.com/c/SpaceX

Comment: If you're asking about timing you should say so. Also you should add units to your numbers and define what exactly you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great image in this [answer.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6679/how-will-spacex-achieve-landing-of-the-falcon-9-first-stage)

Including it here since there are many components and the image does a nice job of explaining it all.

[image: Landing schematic]

If you want to watch this from a 'birds eye view' you can watch the video SpaceX posted from the Sept 2020 flight for the SAOCOM mission sped up.

[SAOCOM Launch and Landing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXgLyCYuYA4)

Comment: Is there any video simulation available too?

Comment: One note on that image: the "boostback burn" is optional.  If SpaceX is going for a drone-ship landing, the ship can instead be placed further downrange so the booster can land on it with just the "reentry" and "landing" burns, using the boostback fuel to instead give the upper stage a bit more of a push.

Comment: @Mark True.  Boostback is more for RTLS.  But could still do it in this case. Depends on mission I suppose.  Starlink being most common, and heaviest, not happening, since they are landing as far downrange as they need

Comment: I mean a 3D animation where the first stage is shown from a distance